# What is the best way to match a field with multiple IDs stored in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a column called "owners", this contains the IDS for users that are connected with that particular record.

I currently delimit the data with ",". So for example

```
ID | Name | Owners
1 | Bob | 1,4,5
```

When doing a select on this I was intending to use  the following SQL:

```
select * from table where owner='$profile' or owner like '%,$profile%' or owner like '%$profile,%'
```

but now I realise this is flawed (searching for 5 would match 5, 15, 25, even 50).

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: The correct way is not to store multiple values in a single field separated with commas. It will only result in headaches.

Comment: Not recommend to spend extra effort to parse the data if database itself can serve the purpose, e.g. using relation table.

Comment: There are times when you want to add delimited data to a field, but these are usually very limited scenarios. In your use-case, you need to use a separate table ```person_owners``` with fields person_id, owner_id with a combination primary key on both fields. Then add the data, and do your lookups on this table.

Answer (score 2):

@Amarnasan is correct: Don't store multiple values in a single field separated with commas!

In Bill Karwin's `SQL Antipatterns` book this is called the Jaywalking antipattern.

The correct way is to create a an intersection table which joins `owners` to the first table. You would have multiple rows in the intersection table representing the multiple owners for each record:

```
Record_ID | Owners_ID
1 | 1
1 | 4
1 | 5
```

Your query would then look something like:

```
select * from table
join intersection_table
where intersection_table.record_id = table.id
and intersection_table.owners_id = '$profile'
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be storing data this way (it's not 'sound' database design).

But if you insist on doing so, you could make sure your other numbers don't satisfy this condition by explicitly including the commas yourself:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ',' + owner + ',' LIKE '%,5,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, I would not use this method for storing data.. but in the case that you can't change it or require a patch before refactoring I would use the following:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(:profile, Owners) > 0
```

[See FIND_IN_SET docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Arth's answer use PDO syntax, so do not be confused by the `:profile`. You use `$profile`, as a php variable,  if you haven't switched to PDO yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use find_in_set

```
SELECT * FROM table where find_in_set($profile,owner)
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) is a great workaround **only if** you don't have time to [normalize the values and split them out into other tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

**Careful though,** This method is very sensitive and will look for the entire value between each comma. So if you store numbers with spaces like `"1, 2, 3"`, then the values that will be returned will be `"1"`, `" 2"`, and `" 3"`, not `"1"`,`"2"`,`"3"` (notice the first group has spaces).